# If id (for each sql row) exists update else insert

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables. In first table i have columns id,name,
I want to check in the second table if id(from first table) exists, then update name.
If id doesnt exist insert id,name.

I'm using this code but it doesnt work.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CheckNone = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT id from test) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con);
con.Open();
var result = (int)CheckNone.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == 0)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into test(id,name) select id,name from Tamio.dbo.memberform", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
else
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" update test set test.name select memberform.name from Tamio.dbo.memberform", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

I Want succeed this.
[image]

Comment: 1) why split this in to 3 queries, why not make it a single 3 line query? 2) You need to be more specific about "it doesn't work", in what way does it not work? Please tell us the specific incorrect the behavior or the error you are getting.

Comment: This code works in two statements. In first makes insert, in second makes update. I want to combine these two situations. How will i make it a single 3 line query?

Comment: Sql server has a [merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement designed specifically for this kind of thing (widely known as "upsert").

Comment: Your second sql statement doesn't look valid. What are you setting your column `test.name` to?

Comment: I found what i was looking for:   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" UPDATE test2 SET test2.name = test.name FROM test, test2 WHERE test2.id = test.id",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              SqlCommand cmdi = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO test2 SELECT * from test WHERE test.id not IN (select o.id from test2 o)",con);
              cmdi.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT id from test) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

That will return 1 if *any* id exists

The update does not match up rows in any way
Not even valid syntax

```
update test set test.name select memberform.name from Tamio.dbo.memberform
```

syntax may be off as from memory but merge will do this

```
MERGE 
   table2 AS target
USING 
   table1 AS source
ON 
   target.id = source.id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET target.name = source.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (id, name) VALUES (source.id, source.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you use 3 query ? Make it one :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT id from test) UPDATE test SET *test.name (SELECT memberform.name FROM Tamio.dbo.memberform)*; ELSE INSERT INTO test(id,name) SELECT id,name FROM Tamio.dbo.memberform;
```

But your update code isnt valid. Probably its the cause of your problem :).

Comment: The will not work.  SELECT memberform.name FROM Tamio.dbo.memberform returns all rows.  It does not match up row.

Comment: Thats why i made that clear with that * icons :).

Comment: So you knew it did not work and some how the * made that clear?

Comment: Yes i knew. Made clear for him.